# Unable to use verbatim string in Regex constructor instantiation

Tags: c#, regex

I'm attempting to new-up a Regex object using a pattern.  The string pattern and the original regex are below:

```
string search = "Root\\Hill";
var regex = new Regex(search, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This throws a `System.ArgumentException` exception so I'd like to convert the pattern to a verbatim string.  I've tried this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@search, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

and this:

```
string verbatim = @search;
var regex = new Regex(verbatim , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

but to no avail.  They both throw the same exception.  When I'm debugging, putting the "raw" string in the Regex constructor (eg. `new Regex(@"Root\\Hill", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`) works, but my search value changes of course.

How can I use a verbatim string with a variable?

Comment: It would m have to be `\\\\\` There should be something like `Regex.Escape`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` sign must be just before the string literal, not before the variable name:

```
string search = @"Root\\Hill";
var regex = new Regex(search, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Putting the `@` sign before an identifier is just a way to use a language keyword as an identifier, it's unrelated to verbatim strings.

Comment: if he's wanting to match `Root\Hill` then his string should be `@"Root\Hill"`

Comment: The value in search is coming from the UI so I have no idea what it is, thus it's immediately stored in a variable.  If you can only use `@` when you know the string, how can I properly handle escape characters if my string is in a variable?

Comment: @im1dermike: You seem to be confused about what the purpose of the verbatim literal is. It does not change the contents of an existing string, and it is not an operator. It is purely a request to the compiler to say "this literal string appears in the code exactly as I wish it to appear in memory".  If you want to write code that changes strings at runtime, you're going to have to write that code.

Comment: @im1dermike, if the regex pattern is entered by the user, you shouldn't need to escape anything; it's the user's responsibility to write a valid pattern.

Comment: You're right guys.  My apologies.  I had read a little blurb about verbatim strings which turns out was confusing.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you're using is the syntax for "treat this identifier as an identifier even if it is a keyword". That is, you can say:

```
int @for = @class + @struct;
```

And the compiler won't complain. This is a *verbatim identifier*.  See

http://ericlippert.com/2013/09/09/verbatim-identifiers/

for more details.

Verbatim string literals put the `@` before the string literal:

```
string search1 = "Root\\Hill";  //  backslash is escaped: Root\Hill
string search2 = @"Root\\Hill";   //  backslash is literal: Root\\Hill
```